# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I have framework where I have used `XMPPFramework`.Its work fine in my framework but when I add to my project and compile ,will get below error.

`ld: framework not found KissXML for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

It was working fine in `xcode 7.x` but when I converted to `swift 3 (xcode 8)`
I get this problem.

Tried cleaning / shift + cmd + k + deriveredData clean still no luck . any suggestions / help to resolve this will be much appreciated

thanks for help in advance

Comment: Seems like the framework was not built for the Simulator. You may want to try running it on a real device instead. To build a fat framework for both the Simulator and real devices, research the `lipo` tool.

Comment: @ThanhPham hay thanks for replying. I tried same yet not resolved. Im getting same error

Comment: I solved it by installing in `XMPPFramework` in my main project. I know its not best solution.But it fixed my issue.Any suggestions / help to resolve this will be much appreciated